TypeScript Cannot Find Module astro:content
I've upgraded my astro blog to the latest versions and got a problem using the content module of astro. My GitHub Actions CI jobs are failing due to a TypeScript error indicating that the module astro:content cannot be found or its corresponding type declarations are missing. This is not happening on running pnpm check (or astro check) locally
src/content/config.ts(1,37): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'astro:content' or its corresponding type declarations.

Here is my tsconfig.json:
{
  "extends": ["astro/tsconfigs/strict", "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.json"],
  "exclude": ["dist"], // exclue astro dist folder from `astro check`, should be fixed with v5 https://github.com/withastro/language-tools/issues/643#issuecomment-2361038516
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "@layouts/*": ["src/layouts/*"]
    }
  }
}

And here the github-Action-yml:
jobs:
  ...
  typecheck:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node: [20]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: pnpm/action-setup@v4
        with:
          version: 9
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node }}
          cache: "pnpm"
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pnpm install
      - name: Run typecheck
        run: pnpm check


Locally inside the .astro folder the types.d.ts file is generated with following content:
/// <reference types="astro/client" />
/// <reference path="astro/content.d.ts" />

For local setup it seems to be fine. Why is my pipeline failing?

Ok i think I got the problem. I need to manually generate the .astro folder inside the CI with something like astro sync
